# turning numbers into date and time

Tags: php, date, numbers

How do turn some numbers, i.e. 20020415 into the date 15/04/2002? Everything I do seems to change 20020415 to today's date. Here is what I have so far:

```
//[DOB]
function dob_func( $atts )
{
$dob = get_field('dob');
$dob = date('d/m/Y');
return $dob;
}
add_shortcode( 'dob', 'dob_func' );
```

The code generates a shortcode for a wordpress plugin. "get_field('dob');" will return the field 20020415 but then " $dob = date('d/m/Y');" turns it into todays date? I have been looking for solutions for hours.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php

Comment: Use either [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) (older) or use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/datetime.createfromformat) (newer, with some nice features, but is seems like you don't need that).

Comment: Your format is `Ymd` anyway

Comment: Thanks for replies. Trying to format from Ymd to dmY

Comment: Could I pester for an example. I just need the code for turning 20020415 into 15/04/2002. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @user1721230 I have posted a new answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the substr function? Assuming it's always going to return the numbers in the yyymmdd format?

```
      $year = substr("20020415", 0,4);
      $month = substr("20020415",4,2);
      $day = substr("20020415",6,2);
      $arry = Array()
      $arry[0] = $day;
      $arry[1] = $month;
      $arry[2] = $year
      $formattedDate = implode('/', $arry);
      //Do what you'd like from here
```

It's just a thought, separate your vars, then go from there. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.
http://www.php.net/substr

Comment: Will do when I get 15 rep

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and its [createFromFormat() method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will give you a much simpler solution than the currently accepted answer:-

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20020415');
$dob = $date->format('d/m/Y');
echo $dob
```

**Output:**

```
15/04/2002
```